# Rails: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've run into a problem while trying to clone a repo and get it up and running. 
 When I run bundler I encounter the error below.  For some reason it's not liking the `gem pg_query`.  Inside the error message I see: `error: '__int128' is not supported for this target` but this is beyond my scope of knowledge. I've tried reading similar posts but have yet to find a working solution.

```
Fetching pg_query 0.11.4
Installing pg_query 0.11.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
compiling src/pg_query.c
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/postgres.h:47:0,
                 from src/pg_query_internal.h:4,
                 from src/pg_query.c:2:
./src/postgres/include/c.h:298:9: error: '__int128' is not supported for this ta
./src/postgres/include/c.h:298:24: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaratio
./src/postgres/include/c.h:299:18: error: '__int128' is not supported for this t
make: *** [src/pg_query.o] Error 1
cp: cannot create regular file `./../../spec/files/': No such file or directory
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling pg_query_ruby.c
pg_query_ruby.c: In function 'pg_query_ruby_parse':
pg_query_ruby.c:80:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wde
pg_query_ruby.c: In function 'pg_query_ruby_normalize':
pg_query_ruby.c:99:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wde
pg_query_ruby.c: In function 'pg_query_ruby_fingerprint':
pg_query_ruby.c:115:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wd
linking shared-object pg_query/pg_query.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpg_query
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_query.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extens

An error occurred while installing pg_query (0.11.4), and Bundler cannot continu
Make sure that `gem install pg_query -v '0.11.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried running `gem install pg_query -v '0.11.4'` and get the same result.

Comment: have you installed `postgres` database on your system ? Also used `pg` gem in `Gemfile` and use `pg` database in your application.

Comment: Can you do two things 1)  check bundler version using bundler -v 2)  Then check at the end of  your Gemfile.lock there must be some bundler version share it here

Comment: @Aniket Shivam Tiwari ok...  So I have Bundler -v 1.16 and my Gemfile.lock says Bundled with 1.15

Comment: @puneet18 Yes, I have  all of the above

Comment: DId you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so the problem is with your bundler version. Your GemFile specifies lower bundler version but your system has higher bundler version.
Please match the correct bundler version with your Gemfile.lock and install the older version of bundler. Try the below code

```
gem install bundler -v '~> 1.15'
bundle _1.15_ install
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried that and am still getting the same error. Even after I run `gem install bundler -v '~> 1.15'`, when I check `bundler -v` it still says I am using version 1.16.    I've tried changing my bundler version a few diffferent ways but no matter what when I tun `bundler -v` it's still showing -v 1.16.

Comment: first, uninstall all version of bundler and then try the above solution